# How to convert 3 tables into 3 columns but one table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 3 tables in SQL that returns this results:

[image]

For simplicity here are some 3 selects:

```
SELECT 93

SELECT 101

SELECT 1
```

> How can I convert that into one table with 3 columns:

[image]

Comment: So in your final result, do you want the list of the records in each table?

Comment: I just want to have a one table but with 3 columns.

Comment: Are the 93, 101 and 1 queries pulling from a common database? If so, what do the records in that one look like?

Comment: 93, 101, 1 comes from different tables and are a little bit complex to generate, but at the end I have 3 different selects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One method is to just use `select`:

```
select (select 93) as registered,
       (select 101) as authorized,
       (select 1) as rejected
```

You can put your actual queries where the placeholders are.

Comment: What about if I have instead of 1 column 2 columns. Thanks a lot

Comment: @VAAA . . . If you have another question, you should ask it as a question -- rather than in a comment -- along with appropriate data and desired results.